# How does reputation work on meta?

Tags: support, reputation, meta

I know you cannot gain rep on meta, but if you downvote on meta, will that affect your meta rep? Furthermore, would that change be reflected in my main account?

Comment: your main account changes your meta account, not the other way around. There can be a slight time delay, since meta is not in sync. But your main site rep IS your meta rep. NOTHING you do on meta changes rep in ANY way

Comment: On meta?  Nobody cares.

Comment: So there is no incentive for not spamming, destructive edits, etc.?

Comment: From the FAQ on Meta: *Voting here does not cost or earn you reputation; your Meta reputation is simply a copy of your Stack Overflow reputation (synchronised once every hour). This means that downvotes on your posts do not subtract from your reputation, and upvotes do not add to it. This site is meant for everyone to participate in, and downvoting and upvoting happens more freely for it.*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your reputation on Meta Stack Overflow is your reputation on the main site, cached every hour or so.  Nothing you do or that happens here can affect it.

Specifically, that means downvotes you cast will not affect your main site reputation.

**This is not true on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)**, as that acts like a main site and you have your own separate reputation there.

Comment: So how do you gain/lose reputation on Meta SE?

Comment: @Mirabilis The same way you do on any other SE site. Votes and edits.

Comment: Okay, so it only works this way on Meta.SE, not any other Meta sites?

Comment: @Mirabilis Correct.