# Reputation on Meta Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow is synchronized, but not badges

Tags: support, meta

I'm trying to understand all of things about how *Stack Exchange* sites work and I want to clarify why reputation on *Meta Stack Overflow* is synchronized, but badges no?

I have doubt about that, but I want someone to make it clear for me.

Also I have read from this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284737/how-does-reputation-work-on-meta) that reputation on *Meta Stack Overflow* is cached from *Stack Overflow*, so it will not affect reputation at all.

But why is it so?

Comment: Reputation can't be earned on meta, badges can be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your reputation from *main* site follows you to *meta*. Badges do not. You need to earn them seperately on meta.

For the "Reputation",

> Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you; it is earned by convincing your peers that you know what you’re talking about.

and

> The primary way to gain reputation is by posting good questions and useful answers. Votes on these posts cause you to gain (or sometimes lose) reputation.

As for the "badges"

> Besides gaining reputation with your questions and answers, you receive badges for being especially helpful.

To clarify, your account is *primarily* associated with the *main* site. Your reputation relects your *trustworthyness*.

If you want to talk *about* the main site (i.e., working and policies), *meta* is there. Meta description is in this form, in general,

> Meta `<Main sitename>` is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of `<Main sitename>` rather than discussing `<Primary target of Main site>` itself.

for example, for SO and Meta SO,

> Meta Stack Overflow is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Stack Overflow rather than discussing programming itself.

Also, FWIW, if you see,

- [This is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) to the "Badges" in Stackoverflow
- [This is the link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) to the "Badges" in Meta stackoverflow

and *they are different*.

Comment: another thanks for links, I didn't know they are different!

Comment: @Yurets I wish thanks would have come in form of beer !!! Just kiddin, You're welcome. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your rep on meta is simply whatever you earned from the main site. This has two advantages.

1. We can see how experienced a meta user is with the corresponding main site.
2. It serves as a reminder that voting on meta works slightly differently, so don't fret about your rep here.

Badges are not synched, but are there any purely total rep-based badges even?

Comment: another words, reputation shows  activity on *StackOverflow* and badges show the activity on *Meta* for ranging users confidence exactly on *Meta*... Do I make sense?