# Why can't low rep users downvote on meta?

Tags: discussion, meta, new-users

[This help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) suggests that voting has a completely different point on the meta site. Voting on meta is the antithesis of voting on SO. Here downvote = I disagree and upvote = I agree.

> Voting is different on meta.
>   Like normal Stack Exchange sites, Meta allows members to vote on questions and answers. For most posts, votes reflect the perceived usefulness: well-written, well-reasoned, well-researched posts tend to get more attention and more upvotes. Highly-voted and frequently-linked posts may become part of the community-curated FAQ or codified as part of the site’s Help pages.
>
> Unlike normal Stack Exchange sites, Meta invites the community to discuss, debate and propose changes to the way the *community* itself behaves, as well as how the software itself works. On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself

While I completely understand why users with low rep aren't trusted by the community to say if a question or answer is good enough, as they have not proven professional knowledge or knowledge about how this community works, I don't understand why their voice should carry less wight when voting on features etc.

Can someone explain the rationale?

I am *not* asking about how reputation works here [so this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284737/how-does-reputation-work-on-meta) is not relevant.

I know it only comes from the main site. In fact that's what made me ask this in the first place .

Comment: Is the reputation limit the same on meta as on the main site? I do understand that if they let anyone vote on meta, there is risk of spam- or bot-voting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does reputation work on meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284737/how-does-reputation-work-on-meta)

Comment: @gnat That question is about how votes on meta affect reputation. This question is about the rationale behind the reputation requirement _to be able to vote_ on meta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Users who are relatively new to this platform lack sufficient knowledge of and familiarity with its unique method of operation to have a well-informed opinion about the issues discussed on Meta. This site works very differently from other sites on the Internet, and it has a lot of quirks and nuances. Unless you've participated enough to gain a token amount of reputation, it's *extremely* unlikely that you will be familiar with the site's vision and fundamental principles of operation.

Simply put, the feedback that brand-new users would share via votes is not of sufficient value to be gathered in this way.

[The absolute minimum participation bar for Meta is set to 5 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) for a very similar reason:

> **Why do I need 5 rep to post there?**
>
> Your reputation on meta is the same as your reputation on the parent site.
>
> You can always read meta with no rep at all.
>
> Because we allow anonymous participation, we require a small bit of parent site reputation to prevent spam, and ensure that meta is for active, engaged members of the community.

Between 5 and 15 reputation (where you gain the privilege to [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)), you can still post to Meta, either questions or answers, allowing you to provide a logical, reasoned explanation of your point of view—and others to post comments explaining where you might be misunderstanding some fundamental principle/vision for the site. Downvoting similarly comes at [an even higher reputation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).

Answer (score 10):

Because votes also still have the same meaning as they have on main. On meta, they have additionally on specific type of posts an additional meaning where your vote might carry your disagreement.

We know the disagreement of many < 125-rep users with the down vote system, the close vote system and the quality-ban system. We don't need their flood of down-votes to show their disgruntlement.

Besides, with 15 reputation users can upvote all the counter proposals that are often posted as answers on proposals they disagree with. And if such answer not yet exist they can write an answer that makes their argument explicit. Then others can upvote that.

So there are plenty of options already for users that are new to Meta to express their opinion. Giving them privileges on Meta before they earned some trust on the Main site is not needed. There are other means to have their voices carry weight.

Comment: That's the thing I agree with the down vote system, the close vote system and the quality-ban system on the main site where experience makes a big difference. I am asking why it makes a difference here? Why should your opinion matter more?

Comment: _Why should the opinion of someone who invested thousands of hours in the site and is deeply involved in content curation matter more when discussing this site and mainly curation/moderation issues than someone who has not contributed enough to earn him at least 125 reputation?_ Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @ErikA if the answer is yes, do you want try an answer?